# Chrome extensions How to run background file function every 2 sec

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My extension needs to synch some data=[] with other server every 2 seconds. Also background page will have some events listeners which should be triggered very often.
I'm not sure with the first task, should I use infinite loop?

Comment: `setInterval(function(){ code here }, 2000)`. However, I strongly discourage you from using such a short interval. It's extremely unlikely that the state is significantly changed in two seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval` as Rob W suggested but there is a new API coming up called [chrome.alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/alarms) that should be a better choice for your extension. You can read more about it [here](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/06/put-your-extensions-on-diet-with-event.html).

Comment: `chrome.alarms` have a minimum granularity of 1 minute though.

Comment: Chrome 120: Starting in Chrome 120, the minimum alarm interval has been reduced from 1 minute to 30 seconds. For an alarm to trigger in 30 seconds, set periodInMinutes: 0.5.